# Change order of autocompletion loading for ZSH

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

Trying to implement my own flag completion for java I broke the existing one. :-)

What I've done is (among others for sure) `unfunction` and `autoload` calls, to see if my module worked. I think it changed the order of loading autocompletion modules.

So, how to bring it back the way it was? Because previously _java was loaded first, now it's _java_class and I prefer the other way around. :-)

Files in question are both in standard Unix completion:

```
➜  ~ ll /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_java*                                                                                                                                 [% 16:39:51]
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25K lut  7  2016 /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_java
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 693 lut  7  2016 /usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_java_class
```

Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using oh-my-zsh but I think it's zsh only, since I've not played around with oh-my-zsh here but with `$fpath` (just through export, so for one session) and `unfunction` and `autoload`.

Comment: Usually one leaves the system `$fpath` directories alone; instead, put any new completions in a directory listed first in `$fpath`. Not sure why you'd need to fiddle with `unfunction` and `autoload`...

Comment: For debugging of my _java_flags completion @thrig as per https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org

Comment: Also, it was done via export so just for a session.

Comment: If you've been messing around in the vendor space, one way to restore The Way Things Were would be to uninstall the package, delete anything left behind (in particular in that `/usr/share/zsh/functions` dir), and reinstall the `zsh` package.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind - but for later. The vendor space...?